# Is it possible to access a public user known folder from a Windows Store application?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I would like to access the videos public folder from the user computer from a Windows Store application.

C:\Users\Public\Videos

But when I use KnownFolders.VideosLibrary it only return files on the user folder, not the public one. How do I get access to the public folder?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't worked with it enough to provide much of an answer. However, I did have a thought, would it be easier to just ask the user to pick a folder?

Comment: Have you tried to go on a Windows 8 machine and using the command prompt to get a list of environment variables? Then using the Envirnment Variable for the location

Comment: That's a client request. He is going to deploy a computer with video files on the public folder and the application should list all the available videos.

Comment: @BenP.Dorsi-Todaro, how do I do that from a windows store application? I believe that it is not possible.

Comment: In short, you can't. But like what Kyle mentioned above, use the FolderPicker to allow user to specify which folder he wants to access. Caveat here is that you will need to specify the folder every time you run the app.